# Birthday paradox derivation: different approach

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, balls-in-bins

I usually use randomization in algorithms so I am familiar with basics of probability but nothing much advanced. I have gone through the derivation for Birthday Paradox (Cormen et al) and decided to do the same thing in a slightly different way.

(Lets talk in terms of balls and bins. Let there be m balls and n bins).
Let E_ij be the event that two balls i and j end up in same bin. Clearly, $ Pr(E_{ij}) = \frac{1}{n} $.

I claim: probability that there exists at least 2 balls which end up in same bin <= $\sum Pr(E_{ij})$; by union bound. Firstly, is this claim correct? I guess it is not since I don't get the same answer by this formulation. Just for the sake of completeness, $\sum Pr(E_{ij}) = {m \choose 2} * \frac{1}{n}$

I want to get my understanding right and thats why I want to know why this is wrong. I am almost sure that I am messing this up in some very fundamental concept. I am just not able to find which one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are counting with $\sum_{1\leq i < j \leq m} \Pr[E_{i,j}]$ is the *expected number of collisions*, i.e. the expectation of $X$, defined as the number of (pairs of balls that fall in the same bin). What you want is the probability to have at least one of these pairs: an loose upperbound is indeed be given by Markov's Inequality, which states that $$\Pr[X \geq 1] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{1}$$ (since $X$ is a non-negative r.v.).

But what do you mean by "I don't get the same answer by this formulation"? (depending on what you mean, it may come from the fact that Markov's inquality is usually not tight, and so the analysis does not result in the optimal conclusion).

Comment: I see. By "I don't get the same answer by this formulation" I meant the answer for typical Birthday paradox question, i.e how many balls should be there s.t probability of collision is less than 1/2.

I think I understand now why this upper bound is loose. For example, Pr(i and j collide) + Pr(j and k collide) <= $\frac{2}{n}$ by this method whereas the actual probability of i,j and k ending up in same bin is $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: But is it up to constants, or in terms of the dependence on $n$ itself? What do you get, what did you want to get?

Comment: I get the value of m>=20 while the actual answer is m>=23.
(I use n=365 here) i.e in my case, probability of collision is more than 1/2 when m >= 20.

Comment: But you here get an **upperbound** $p(m,n)$ on the probability of collisions $p^\ast(m,n)$, not a lowerbound... finding the minimum $m$, $m_{.5}$, for which $p(m_{.5},n) > 1/2$ does not guarantee you that $p^\ast(m_{.5},n) > 1/2$.